# A problem in none-special integrals

Tags: integration

We know that $y=\sin x$ is an odd function ;
It means that, for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ ,we have $f (-x) = -f (x) .$
So we expect that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin x dx$ should be Zero, but it's not!!
But why?????

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\pm \infty} (-\cos(x))$ does not converge

Comment: My problem is proving this answer based on graph of the function!

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume we're talking about an improper Riemann integral.  By definition
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin(x) \, dx$$
means something like
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \lim_{M \to -\infty} \int_M^N \sin(x) \, dx$$
provided that such a limit exists.  Now (assuming that relevant limits exist)
\begin{align*}
\lim_{N \to \infty} \lim_{M \to -\infty} \int_M^N \sin(x) \, dx
&= \lim_{N \to \infty} \lim_{M \to -\infty} - \cos(N) + \cos(M) \\
&= -\lim_{N \to \infty} \cos N + \lim_{M \to -\infty}\cos(M)
\end{align*}

Of course,
$$\lim_{M \to -\infty} \cos(M)$$
doesn't exist.  So the integral doesn't either.

Comment: In calculating this integral, we have a Symmetric interval, which means we must choose M & N from a same distance from zero point. So based on graph of f(x)=sinx function, in this situation the consequent area is zero(because the area of left &right side of zero point is equal but symmetry) , so we expect that the answer of main integral to be Zero, too!!

Comment: "we have a Symmetric interval, which means we must choose M & N from a same distance from zero point"

No, this is incorrect.  Re-examine the definition of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$.